# xlwings calculation incorrect when passing value to UDF

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwings

I am pulling data from Bloomberg through TIA to python in order to calculate beta. When I run the code in the Python Compiler I get a correct calculation. When I hard code a cusip into the Python code, I also get the right calculation. However, when I pass the cusip through excel to python I get an incorrect value. The value seems to have no correlation with any calculations done. Is there a wrapper I need to provide in order to correctly pass data from Excel to Python other than the @xw.func identifier? For those who do not know the cusip needs to look something like this for TIA, '/cusip/abcde123@BGN' Where abcde123 are 8 characters representing the cusip and BGN is the pricing location.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question needs to incorporate your code, your problem, what you have done to resolve it and what you intend to achieve. Please learn more on [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that when passing a cusip through excel I left the single quotes in the cell, for example I passed '/cusip/...@BGN' instead of /cusip/...@BGN. Not sure why this changed the value so drastically but everything is calculating correctly now